# Looking for full documentation of Snowflake privileges

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have encountered some privileges in Snowflake for which I can't find documentation where I would expect to find them (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html):

- ADD SEARCH OPTIMIZATION
- CREATE TAG
- REBUILD
- REFERENCE USAGE

What do these privileges do, and where are they documented? I have only been able to find scant references on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADD SEARCH OPTIMIZATION

[What Access Control Privileges Are Needed For the Search Optimization Service?](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization-service.html#what-access-control-privileges-are-needed-for-the-search-optimization-service)

> To add or remove search optimization for a table, you must have the following privileges:
>
> You must have OWNERSHIP privilege on the table.
>
> You must have ADD SEARCH OPTIMIZATION privilege on the schema that contains the table.

---

CREATE TAG

[Summary of DDL Commands, Operations, and Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-tagging.html#summary-of-ddl-commands-operations-and-privileges)

> Create tag.
>
> A role with the USAGE privilege on the parent database and schema with the CREATE TAG privilege in the same schema.

---

REBUILD

[Insert Using Overwrite](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#insert-using-overwrite)

---

REFERENCE USAGE

[GRANT  … TO SHARE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege-share.html#usage-notes)

> Use the REFERENCE_USAGE privilege when sharing a secure view that references objects belonging to multiple databases, as follows:
>
> The REFERENCE_USAGE privilege must be granted individually to each database.
>
> The REFERENCE_USAGE privilege must be granted to a database before granting SELECT on a secure view to a share.

Comment: Thank you! On https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#usage-notes, I see "To use the OVERWRITE option on INSERT, you must use a role that has DELETE privilege on the table because OVERWRITE will delete the existing records in the table." Does REBUILD grant this DELETE privilege?

Comment: There is still some information missing. Regarding the REFERENCE_USAGE - which privileges does one need to be able to grant this privilege on a Database to a Share? It seems like either Ownership on the database or the global MANAGE GRANTS on the account is needed. But it is not mentioned in the documentation anywhere I could find.

Comment: @BenRosenzweig The [REFERENCE_USAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges#database-privileges) privilege is a database level privilege so in order to grant it you should be owner of DB or have a role that is "higher" in hierarchy that database owner role or have a global privilege:`MANAGE GRANTS` `Grants the ability to grant or revoke privileges on any object as if the invoking role were the owner of the object.`.

Comment: @BenRosenzweig "But it is not mentioned in the documentation anywhere I could find" -> [Discretionary Access Control (DAC)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview#access-control-framework) - `Each object has an owner, who can in turn grant access to that object.` and `In addition, each securable object has an owner that can grant access to other roles`